# Java - How to create/write a custom annotation and make it work?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

How to create a custom annotation and make it work and i don't want to use "main" method and "spring bean post processor" because for this the class should be spring component if i use my custom annotation in my class.

And the processor should process and search annotation in jar also.
The the Retention for this annotation is "RUNTIME" and target is on "FIELD".

I have used "Spring 3.1" in my project.

Thanks.

Comment: "make it work" is to vague to answer. Specify what you have, what you need and how what you have is failing to make what you need work.

Comment: _something_ has to honor your annotation, because normally it'll be ignored. if you dont want to use spring runtime for this, have a look at compiletime or runtime aspect weaving

Comment: What do you mean by 'create a custom annotation and make it work'? Do  you just mean how do you write a java annotation class that makes any class annotated with it a component?

Comment: @Peter, I have changed my question title. And i have nothing. 1st i need to research. Because i know how to write and use it in "main" method but not in servlet environment.

Comment: @Radai, It will be better if you provide some example with configuration for "runtime aspect weaving", because i want to create a "Annotation with "RUNTIME" Retention.

Comment: @BenGreen, I have clearly mentioned in my question that i want to create/write a annotation with target "FIELD" not on the "class".

Comment: @MarcoAcierno, yes the annotation processor will be created with the help of "Reflection".

Answer (score 3):

Like this make one class

```
package com.comment;

    import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
    import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
    import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
    import java.lang.annotation.Target;


    @Documented
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Inherited
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface MethodInfo{   
        public enum Developer {
           Ashish,Chetan,Jatin,Dipesh
        }
        public enum Status {
           Complet,Running,Pending
        }   
        Developer createdBy();      
        Status status();
        String modifyDate();
        String comments();
    }
```

use like in controller

```
@RequestMapping({ "/home" })
@MethodInfo(comments = "", createdBy = Developer.Ashish, 
                    modifyDate = "06-03-2014", status = Status.Running)
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
```

Comment: and this gets picked-up at runtime by what ... ?

Comment: You should have to call the annotation from bean factory variable @radai

Comment: @JanakDhanani, can you please explain with example ?

Comment: @RunWith(YourAnnotationClassName.class)

or
visit:http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/
@user3515080